# No Suitable Driver for JDBC in Android App

Tags: sql-server, database, jdbc, jtds

I have downloaded the jar JDBC file and successfully added into my app/src/lib file.
Furthermore I also tried with the JTDS-JDBC library but I was getting the same exact exceptions which were:

1. > Network exception can't connect to 127.0.0.1/1433 ECOREFUSED
2. > java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

For Exception `#1` I searched out and found some posts that the main reason for this exception to be thrown is the lack of memory, hence I increased SQLServer's memory to 4GB which didn't solve my problem.

For both libraries I tried to establish a connection in order to achieve an INSERTION into my SQLServer database with the only difference that for JTDS-JDBC I used the following:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"))
```

I'm running the following code:

```
try {
     /*Declare the JDBC objects.*/
     Connection con = null;
     Statement stmt = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;


     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

     String constring = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=bumpit;integratedSecurity=true;";

     con = DriverManager.getConnection(constring);

     /*Create and execute an SQL statement.*/
     stmt = con.createStatement();
     String SQL = "INSERT INTO BumpItUsers (name,address,mobile,password) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + address + "','" + address + "','" + password + "')";
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);


     con.close();
     return true;

     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return false;
     }
 }
```

Any solution will be accepted!

Comment: Why a src/lib directory? A lib is never a src. It is a binary and must be added to the classpath

Comment: Hopefully you do not want to use the SQL Server on a Smartphone side

Comment: I also tried to simply let Grandle compile the library by itself simply using 
`compile 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'`, but didn't see any difference

Comment: what version of JDBC you use if tds-1.3.1 try earlier one   jtds-1.3.0

Comment: `1.Network exception can't connect to 127.0.0.1/1433 ECOREFUSED` sounds like there is no SQL-Server running on your local machine. Or it runs on a different port

Comment: I tried with jtds-1.3.0 and I received `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver` again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `localhost`, from the standpoint of the Android device, is *the Android device*. This is how `localhost` works everywhere: it refers to the machine on which the code is running. SQL Server does not run on Android. You would need to change your code to refer to the actual IP address or domain name of the machine running SQL Server.

Second, few developers use JDBC on Android, for reliability and security reasons.

Comment: In your opinion which DBMS should I use?

Comment: @HelloIT: Use a Web service or something else designed with insecure clients and flaky network connections in mind. If you want to use SQL Server for storing the data, you are welcome to do so, but do not have mobile apps directly talking to the database.